# Add/remove breakpoints in Ace editor by clicking the gutter space

Tags: editor, breakpoints, ace-editor

Does anyone know of an Ace editor API that enables adding or removing breakpoints by clicking the gutter in the editor window? I spent more time than I care to admit looking for this functionality in the [API reference](https://ace.c9.io/#api=&nav=api), source code, forums, blogs, etc. and the best information I found so far is [this answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ace-discuss/sfGv4tRWZdY/ca1LuolbLnAJ) from May 2012. It's a good starting point, but the breakpoints don't move when new lines are inserted in the code above them. I find it hard to believe that Ace doesn't include this in the standard feature set by now, as it's something we've come to expect in any decent code editor and the Cloud9 environment supports it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API provided by Ace for this. Here's the implementation used by Cloud9 https://github.com/c9/c9.ide.run.debug/blob/master/breakpoints.js#L727.
 Most likely it is kept in Cloud9 plugin instead of Ace because it depends on the format in which breakpoints are stored, which might be different for different ides.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Cloud9 code, it is very helpful. However, I didn't get your last sentence. The breakpoints are being added or removed in the editor window by clicking on the gutter; the behavior I would expect is that Ace will store the information and also let clients know about it through a specialized event. The IDE can deal with the data in any way it needs to. I really think this feature belongs with Ace, as it doesn't feel right for IDEs to have to deal with making breakpoints stick to the correct lines of code.